# MEMORY MANAGEMENT issues with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory

**Background:**

PC: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz   4.00 GHz, 64-bit, 16GB RAM, 250GB SSD

I tried installing Windows 10 and it kept crashing at or before 50% with error code; 0x8007025D (Windows cannot install required files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation.)

I tried everything from these forums related to BIOS, memory tests, nothing worked until decided to remove my memory. I had 4 x 4GB Kingston Hyper X blu DRAM modules. I removed 3 of them, leaving 1 x 4GB ram and tried installation again - success.

**Issue:**

I put all the memory back in the PC tried downloading a game - While downloading the game, after about 5-10 minutes, the PC crashes with a blue screen which gives the Stop Code: MEMORY MANAGEMENT.

PC reboots normally and starts again.  I then start up the download again and after about 5-10 minutes the error occurs again and PC reboots.

1. I ran the Windows Memory Diagnostic which reported no errors.
2. I went into Windows Update and downloaded all the optional driver updates that were suggested.

Problem still persists.

I removed 2 of the RAM modules leaving 2 x 4GB but on reboot, I got the blue screen with Stop Code: KERNEL SECURITY CHECK FAILURE before windows even loaded and then after rebooting, another blue screen, this time MEMORY MANAGEMENT again.

I then removed the 2nd RAM module and left just 1 x 4GB and rebooted.  I have been running the download now for 15-20 minutes without issue so I "think" it is ok with just one RAM module...

I don't know how to properly diagnose... My instincts say it is a driver/windows issue using the memory improperly as opposed to the memory itself being corrupted but I don't know how to prove/disprove my theory?

Answer (score 1):

What test you performed for memory test, only the Windows Memory Diagnostic ? I would advise you to perform a memtest here : https://www.memtest86.com/

It takes a while, but you will be sure of the results.

It could also be a DIMM slots issue on your motherboard. Have you tried to change the location of your DIMM ?

The goal is to plug the 4GB DIMM that works on other DIMM slots of your motherboard to eliminate motherboard slots issue. Once done, if everything works on all DIMM slots, you can assume that issue comes from one of your 4 DIMM. You can plug your 4 DIMM on the motherboard and boot on the memtest USB key. You can use the tool provided by mem test to flash the memtest system on the USB key. This video can help you to proceed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDCk04hgVEk

The memtest process consists to 13 tests (read/write tests), the results are quite simple to analys, if everything is fine with your memory, you will have this view at the end of the tests :
[image]

Else, memtest will informed you about errors found like this :
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hidigoudi. Ran the first stick through and got the PASS screen however, I did notice the following: `[Note] RAM may be vulnerable to high frequency row hammer bit flips`. Trying to get time to run the other 3 through the same process

Comment: For your first DIMM problem - https://www.memtest86.com/troubleshooting.htm#hammer - This is a vulnerability on your RAM during heavy use.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing 1 ram at a time and running memtest86.

Turns out one of the sticks was corrupt - kept giving a BSOD with service exception error.

Been running the PC on 3 of the 4 modules and it has been fine.